# Is there a better way to do ICMP Ping with specific local IP address in Java

Tags: java, networking, icmp

I'd like to implement an ICMP ping program in Java, there are two ways to achieve this.

1. Using InetAddress:

   ```
   InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]); 
   inet.isReachable(1000);
   ```
2. Using Process + Command:

   ```
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process mypro = rt.exec("ping " + args[0]);
   mypro.waitFor();
   ```

But they all have shortcomings:

The first way:

- I can not indicate Local IP and indicate TOS, 
  such as: ping -I localip DestIP -Q 120

The second way:

- It does can achieve all of the requirements,but I worry about the performance, 
  because each ping is creating a single process, 
  if I have millions of ping, that would be terrible.

Comment: By the way, ToS has been deprecated in favor of DSCP, and neither actually does anything unless the intermediate devices are configured to to do something with it (not the default, and not available on the public Internet), and there is congestion in the path.

Comment: Are you comfortable writing and linking against native (i.e. JNI) code?

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov Using JNI is same just like invoke ping command? what do you prefer? if you have to choose between the two ways I listed above?

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, I'm using dscp as well, but dscp in TOS, so I have to set TOS. Anyway, the most important thing for me is that how can I indicate my local IP, I mean like: ping -I 10.1.1.1

Comment: 1. The first way doesn't usually use ICMP PING at all: it uses a TCP connection to port 7 (echo); see the Javadoc. 2. Why would you have millions of PINGs?

Comment: Ping is an application, usually provided with the OS. Each version has various flags to do different things, and you could write your own the way the authors of the other ping applications did, but you seem to think it is a simple API, not an application.

Comment: @user207421 using JNI is very different from invoking the ping command. You call into native code without leaving your process or thread, at which point you can use your system's native APIs to send and receive ICMP packets. If I needed to ping millions of devices with the constraints given, I'd use that instead of either of your approaches (or even might use C/C++ directly instead of Java, if feasible)

Comment: @user207421 I'm writing a Network Monitor app, so I need to ping millions ip, that's why the second way totally not work, because it would spawn millions processes.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov thanks! do you have java example which invoke JNI? (I'm a Java guy). Or do you have C/C++ example, maybe I can try it :-)

Comment: @Jack No example handy but [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ping-in-c/) might be a good starting point. You'll unfortunately need to work through the ICMP spec to construct the ping packet, and to parse the response (although there might be a library for this that you can link against, at least on Linux such as [NoPing](https://noping.cc/))